# Override fade function on returning to initial slide, iDangero.us Swiper

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

On [this site](http://anthron.octans.uberspace.de/meta.php) the navigation menu on the left disappears when the gallery is activated. It reappears when the mouse hovers over a `div`  covering the left 230px of the screen (`#leftbar` in the code snippet below). So far so good, but I want this effect to stop when the visitor goes back to the initial slide.

The index numbers are being returned from the iDangero.us Swiper, the slider Plugin I use.
Now, when I navigate from slide 1 to 2 and back to 1, the menu reappears as intended, but it disappears when the mouse leaves the said `div`on the left side of the window, which should only happen on slides index #1 and greater.

For debugging purposes the slide index (coming from the plugin) is displayed in the `title`-tag. As the index is displayed correctly when navigating back and forth through the gallery I think plugin-related issues could be ruled out.

Here's the code:

```
function slidefader(){
  var slideindex = mySwiper.activeIndex;
  $('title').html(slideindex);
  // First slide
  if (slideindex == 0) {
    $('.fade').clearQueue();
    $('.fade').delay(600).fadeIn(200);
    $('.fade2').fadeOut(100);
  }

  // Other slides
  if (slideindex >= 1) {
    $('.fade').clearQueue();
    $('.fade').fadeOut(200);
    $('.fade2').fadeIn();


$('#leftbar').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.fade').fadeIn(200);
})
    $('#leftbar').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.fade').fadeOut(200);
})

  }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you need to use `.off()` several times as follows :

```
function slidefader(){
    var slideindex = mySwiper.activeIndex;
    $('title').html(slideindex);
    // First slide
    if (slideindex == 0) {
        $('.fade').clearQueue().delay(600).fadeIn(200);
        $('.fade2').fadeOut(100);

        $('#leftbar').off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave');
    }

    // Other slides
    if (slideindex >= 1) {
        $('.fade').clearQueue().fadeOut(200);
        $('.fade2').fadeIn();

        $('#leftbar').off('mouseenter').on('mouseenter', function() {
            $('.fade').stop().fadeIn(200);
        }).off('mouseleave').on('mouseleave', function(){
            $('.fade').stop().fadeOut(200);
        });
    }
}
```

For slide #0, any currently attached mouseenter/mouseleave handlers will be removed.

For slide #1, any currently attached mouseenter/mouseleave effect will be removed (to prevent an accumulation of effects) and fresh handlers will be attached.

Although you didn't ask for it, I have also included `.stop()`. This will stop dead any effect(s) that are currently running before initiating the desired effect. Without `stop()`, the desired animation will run after any current effect(s) finish. This is important to cater for a quick mouseenter-mouseleave sequence (or worse, eg. mouseenter-mouseleave-mouseenter-mouseleave-mouseenter-mouseleave).

Note also :

- use of `.on(...)` instead of `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` is optional. It's maybe slighly clearer to use `.on()` when also using `.off()`
- method chaining improves the efficiency of the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it! Thanks also for the valuable hints, I'm always happy to learn something, this is a really elegant solution.